# How to update SQLite with no access to a C compiler or yum in a remote server?

Tags: django, linux, sqlite, gcc, server

I am trying to host a Django (v. 2.2.14) website on Hostgator. However, Django complains about the SQLite version:

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found 3.6.20).`

I have no access to yum in order to update SQLite:

`CRITICAL:yum.cli:Config Error: Error accessing file for config file:///etc/yum.conf`

I tried to compile it from the source code, but I have no access to any C compiler. This is what happens when I try to run `./configure`:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

And this happens when trying to use gcc (because the plan the company I work for bought has no access to C.):

`bash: /usr/bin/gcc: Permission denied`

I need to use Django and I need to use this plan from Hostgator. Is there a way for me to compile gcc or SQLite 3.8.3 on my machine and then just send the files to the remote server? Or any other thing I could do to fix that?

I think I could use Django 1 or any other older version, but that would be too complicated for my case, since my website is already done.

Comment: And a real database is no option either I take it? `psycopg2-binary` would install on linux without needing compilation.

Comment: PostgreSQL is not available on my current plan, can I still install it?

Comment: Same catch-22 I'm afraid. yum or gcc. If you're stuck with this platform then there's not much else to do then downgrade Django, or perhaps fork an older `django.db.backends.sqlite` and stick it in your app, then configure that as backend?

Answer (score 0):

I installed Django 2.0.0 (Probably I could use a more recent version that matched my SQLite version) and it worked.